# WPF DataGrid RowDetailsTemplate focus color

Tags: wpf

I have a DataGrid with a RowDetailsTemplate.  I would like the background color to always match the DataGridTemplateColumn however when focus is moved to a toolbar the focus color is maintained in the DataGridTemplateColumns but lost in the RowDetailsTemplate.  How can I maintain the standard focus behavior on a RowDetailsTemplate?

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <Border
        Margin="0,0,-6,0"
        Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsPresenter}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PreviewMessage}" Padding="32,0,32,8" TextWrapping="Wrap">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" Value="False" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrush}" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrush}" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>

                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" Value="True" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrush}" />
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>

                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the `IsSelectionActive` property instead of the `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` property:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
    AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=IsSelectionActive}" Value="True" />
```